# Что нужно для компонента в админке Joomla 3.7+ для прикрепления к меню

Tags: joomla3

В последних версиях `Joomla CMS` (3.7+), появилась возможность создавать меню и пункты к этим меню не только на стороне паблика но и на стороне админки.
Для того что бы можно было прикрепить свое представление в паблике к пункту меню, необходимо создать файл `default.xml` с metadata->layout узлами и атрибутами `title` и `option` в каталоге где собственно и лежит само представление.

Вопрос, а что нужно сделать чтобы собственные компоненты можно было прикреплять к админским меню?

Собственно само меню я создал через менеджер меню. А вот при создании пункта меню, в типах меню нет моих компонентов, там только компоненты ядра.

P.S. Изучение исходников компонентов ядра и разных xml файлов не дало результата, не нашел я там ничего подобного.

Comment: если я правильно понял, нужно создать группу пунктов для самописного компонента ? думаю ссылка поможет https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_a_menu_type_to_the_site_part

Comment: @Arsen нет вы не правильно поняли вопрос. Собственно вопрос уже решен.

Comment: @Arsen ответ содержится в самом вопросе, равно как и в ссылке что вы дали, `site/views/helloworld/tmpl/default.xml` просто, по каким то причинам у компонентов ядра нет подобных файлов, по этому и возник вопрос как это делается в админке.

Comment: >"  у компонентов ядра нет подобных файлов", например о каком компоненте идёт речь ?

Comment: @Arsen например `com_contact`, для категорий контактов нету файла `default.xml` по пути `administrator\components\com_contact\views\contact\tmpl\` однако же меню с типом категории создать можно и оно отображается в менеджере меню.

Comment: XML которые отвечают за вывод пунктов меню в админке находятся не в директории administrator, они всегда на стороне site, т.е XML для  `com_contact`, для категорий контактов,  файл находится в   components/com_contact/views/category/tmpl/default.xml

Comment: @Arsen вы заблуждаетесь, у меня могут быть на стороне админки одни представления и одни соответствующие им настройки default.xml. А на стороне паблика совершенно другие и они не обязаны быть одинаковыми а наоборот, обязаны быть разными в том случае если фреймворк реализуется для гибкой разработки.